# nginx location pathing issue

Tags: nginx, debian-squeeze

I've got a pretty much default sites-enabled set up in my nginx on debian squeeze and i'm now trying to get it to serve up my munin graphs on myhost/munin/

Heres the location i've added to the config

```
       location /munin
            {
                    root /var/cache/munin/www/;
                    index index.htm index.html;
            }
```

And here is the error I recieve:

```
            2012/07/09 23:52:03 [error] 3598#0: *13 "/var/cache/munin/www/munin/index.htm" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 93.*.*.*, server: , request: "GET /munin/ HTTP/1.1", host: ""
```

This set up used to 'just work' in apache. I'm new to nginx so a bit lost as to why its adding the extra /munin when looking for the path. Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) directive, rather than `root`:

```
location /munin/ {
    alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
root /var/cache/munin/www/;

location /
            {

                    index index.htm index.html;
            }
```

Whats going on here (for dummies mode, no offence):

First we are telling nginx where the DocRoot is, which is /var/.... meaning all future "location" refer to path under this.

then location is simply referencing the top "/" path of this directory